# Cannot access Restlet service using POST from SOAP UI

Tags: json, post, soapui, restlet

I created a series of REST services in Java using Restlets.  The majority of these services use JSON, and I have no problem accessing them using SOAP UI via a GET request.  However, when I try to access POST based services using SOAP UI, the `Representation` entity parameter is always null.  I have searched Stack Overflow as well as the web, but could find nothing which I either haven't already done, or which addresses my problem.

Here is the code for a POST resource which always seems to receive a null `entity`:

```
public class CreateAccountResource extends ServerResource {
    @Post("json")
    public Representation createAccount(Representation entity) throws IOException {
        String message = null;
        boolean result = true;

        try {
            String post = entity.getText();
            Object obj = new JSONParser().parse(post);
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

            String username = (String) jsonObject.get("username");
            String password = (String) jsonObject.get("password");
            String email = (String) jsonObject.get("email");

            // more code
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // handle exception here
        }
    }
}
```

And here is a screen shot from my SOAP UI showing the configuration I used when sending the request:

[image]

In case you are wondering, I am using IntelliJ in debug mode to inspect the value of the `entity`, and the project uses Maven.

Comment: When you say POST request, haven't seen any request in the screen shot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never use *Restlet* however I think that since you specify `@Post("json")` annotation for your `createAccount` method; the method is waiting for a `json` in the `POST` body instead of passing the values as a query parameters.

So probably you must change your actual `POST` with the query parameters to a `POST` call to your URL `http://localhost:8080/MyApp/service/createAccount` passing the parameters in the body as `json`:

```
{
      "username" : "tim",
      "password" : "password",
      "email" : "tim@me.com"
}
```

In *SOAPUI* could be something like:

[image]

Hope it helps,

Comment: I will test this tonight, and if it works you've got 25 points coming at you.

Comment: ok @TimBiegeleisen I hope this solve your problem `:)`, thanks for the feedback

Comment: This is a really helpful answer, and it will allow me to test all my web services end-to-end now (I could previously only test the GET ones).  Thanks again.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen nice to help you `:)`.